# Downloading images from Parse, and not getting the newest version

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I have a very strange problem here that I am pulling my hair out over. I am attempting to download user profile pictures from parse. I have a UITableView with a list of messages and each cell has the name of the user and their profile picture. I am using this code to download:

```
NSLog(@"download called");
PFFile *userImageFile = userObject[@"profilePic"];
[userImageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *imageData, NSError *error) {

    if (!error) {
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
        [self.images setObject:image forKey:userObject[@"username"]];
        cell.profilePic.image = image;
        NSLog(@"added image for %@", userObject[@"username"]);
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"error and couldnt add for %@ is %@", userObject[@"username"], error);
    }     
}];
```

For some reason the image it is downloading is an older version of that image. I have tried changing the profile picture for particular users a number of times and it always displays the same original picture. I have an identical download profile picture method in a different view controller and it downloads the correct one. No idea what is going on here. Has anyone encountered this before? Could someone give me some pointers to what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Parse has a cache from where it loads data if you don't tell it specifically to ignore it

Comment: Is the cache stored in the documents folder for the app? I have also tried deleting an app and doing a fresh install so there is no cache and it downloads the wrong image still.

Comment: Can you check on the parse core if the image file is correct on db? Click on the field and it shows you the image. If it is not then the issue is in the file saving otherwise just try to fetch the object.

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware of the parse caching mechanisms? 
You may have set the cache to "cache-only"?
Moreover the pffile refers to the singular image-file, I guess the code you should look for is before than the block, how do you get the pffile? maybe you have to update the "userobject" with a fetch before then actually retrieve the value (see it as an outdated pointer)?

Comment: I'm not aware of it no. Is the cache stored in the documents folder for the app?

Comment: I don't know but for debug reason, if you delete the app the cache is eliminated as well (by personal experience, i have no proof of this)

Comment: By the way i would give a try to `[userObject fetch]` before than anything else.

Comment: Updating the user object before fetching the PFFile's data may be a solution here

Comment: cache is set by default to ignore it with `kPFCachePolicyIgnoreCache` so there really is nothing for you to do on that end of things. You don't have to tell it to ignore it specifically as stated before, it autonomously does that. The problem lies elsewhere @KexAri

Comment: There was no need to set negative vote, this behaviour just discourage people giving a further help. I have for that reason asked if he accidentally messed with it since the problem clearly does not depend on the posted code.